# Default Button's methods

Tags: java, android

I'd like to gain after onclick button efect similar to default in android, but with own colors

Default button is white or light gray
When i touch button color is changed for one moment (orange)
when release, button's color back to original color (white/light gray)

Which method's are using to this effect ?

I used onTouchListener() to set touched button color
and OnClickListener() to set back original color

But when i scroll group button(inner ScrollView) when i touch any button, color changed but when release button color ofc not change back. Which method should i use ? How can i fix that ?

///////////////////
I created colors in values and define 2 colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="blue">#004080</color>
</resources>
```

I create new folder color and button_state.xml inner this folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

to my button i assign code in xml file

```
android:background="@color/button_states"
```

Now my button have no background, but i don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create xml file defining button states and button color depending on state, for example button_states.xml in res/color folder in your project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/pressed_button_color"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@color/selected_button_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/default_button_color"/>
</selector>
```

define these colors in values/colors.xml

and use this in your layout xml file on the Button element as:

```
android:background="@color/button_states"
```

Comment: it is because you used different selector items in button_states.xml, i tried adding the following items to selector element: <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/white" />
     <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@color/white"/>
     <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/> and this worked for me, so you should consider adding default and state_pressed items

Answer (score 0):

In the xml for your button set its background to the following

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

This will automatically handle the colour changes to be default changes in android

If you want to have you own colours you need to do a custom selector and set it as your background. Something like the following should work:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_focused" />
<item android:drawable="@color/selector_background" />

</selector>
```

Your drawable would be like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/selector_background_pressed"/>

</shape>
```

Not 100% sure but you might just be able to use @color/my_colour directly in the selector rather than referencing a drawable. But this way will definitely work

Comment: hmm, i have error but it expect 11 lvl api or higher , i have to use api 8

Comment: Creating a custom selector like the one I have posted should work for you

Comment: I created selector but it doesn't work , i explained it in my topic

Comment: Create your selector like I have in my example. You need a drawable for your pressed state like the one I have done. Your drawables need to be in res/drawable folder and referenced like `@drawable/filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use of this online [tool](http://android-holo-colors.com/). You just need to choose your desired color set and after download the resources put the in your project resource folder respectively and than apply theme to your you application in Manifest file with name name you set on this online tool("Theme Name" by default AppTheme)

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:label="@string/app_name"android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```